# Call API Endpoint with Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a trial of the sportradar API. I really don't care about sports but I'm trying to learn some Phoenix and Elixir. I'm trying to do something SUPER basic but can't seem to get it going. Basically, I'm trying to build up a URL with the given params and call an API endpoint. Get back the response and populate a view with what came back. Here is what I'm getting stuck on.

#### CONTROLLER

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  render(conn, "index.html")
end

def find_games(conn, params) do
  response = params["find_games"]["calender"]


end
```

I'm basically trying to say at this point call `https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/response["day]/response["month"]/response["year"]/schedule.json?api_key={api_key}`

How do I make an http request with Elixir and Phoenix?

Comment: For HTTP calls use https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example using [HTTPoison.get](https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.html#get/3):

```
%{
  "day" => day,
  "month" => month,
  "year" => year
} = response

url = "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/#{day}/#{month}/#{year}/schedule.json"
headers = []
params = [api_key: api_key]

{:ok, response} <- HTTPoison.get(url, headers, params: params)
Poison.decode(response.body)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have an easier time getting it working and understanding it from outside Phoenix first. As Mike pointed out, HTTPoison is the standard library to use for the task.

To do that, you need to...

1. add HTTPoison as a dependency in your mix file
2. run `mix deps.get`
3. call it from inside your project
4. Parse the response, probably with a JSON decoding library like Jason

Example:

```
require Logger
# define your url and api_key
# ...
case HTTPoison.get(url, [], api_key: api_key) do
  {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    Jason.decode(body)
  {:ok, response} ->
    Logger.info("Sport Radar API status not 200, response: #{inspect(response)}")
    Jason.decode(response.body)
  error ->
    Logger.error("Sport Radar API error: %{inspect error})
end
```

A few years a video that goes through [putting HTTPoison into an empty project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqxyhJewKjI&t=5m13s), making API calls, decoding the responses, etc, from `iex` and then from inside a new mix project. It's all the same now as then, except that the popular JSON library is now `Jason`, not `Poison`.